# Divide binary array into three parts such that each part represent same decimal

Tags: algorithm

Given a binary array, divide array into three parts such that each part represent same decimal.

```
Eg arr[] = {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1}
```

Above array can be divided in the following way:

```
{1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, {1}. Now each part represent same decimal.
```

One simple approach would be to iterate starting from 1 and check each decimal can divide the array into three equal parts.

Is there any efficient algorithm for this.

Comment: count the numbers of ones (multiple of 3) and split them correctly. Adjust where you split acoording to the values of the right part (its value can't change)

Comment: Do you need to detect that no solution is possible? Not all binary arrays can be split in the manner that you describe.

Comment: @Jim Mischel We have to identify whether we can split the array in such a manner

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of set bits. There's no solution if this number isn't divisible by three. Say it is, and that there are 3k set bits. Find the positions of the first, k+1, and 2k+1 set bits. Keep incrementing all three positions and comparing until you get to the last set bit or get a disagreement. If you get to the last set bit with all three agreeing then you have a solution.